# Threejs: How to export an imported obj with Draco compressor

Tags: javascript, three.js

I only have limited javascript skills, i can get basic things working in threejs. Now I am struggeling with the draco exporter.

@ Threejs.org there is an [example of the Draco exporter](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=draco#misc_exporter_draco)

This example uses a generated mesh and is working perfectly:

```
// export mesh

            var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotBufferGeometry( 50, 15, 200, 30 );
            var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
            mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
            mesh.castShadow = true;
            mesh.position.y = 25;
            scene.add( mesh );
```

I can import the .obj and this also works fine

```
new OBJLoader()
.setPath( '../models/mymodel/' )
.load( 'mymodel.obj', function ( mesh ) {

    mesh.traverse( function ( child ) {

        if(child.name=='mymodel_part1'){                        
                    child.material = Material1;
        }
        if(child.name=='mymodel_part2'){                        
                    child.material = Material2;
        }
        if(child.name=='mymodel_part3'){                        
                    child.material = Material3;
        }

    } );

    scene.add( mesh );

} );
```

Now I want to export the mesh, and this does not work, I get a "TypeError: mesh is undefined".

So the Type is not correct, but what should it be, and how do I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `OBJLoader.load()` does not produce a group but an instance of `THREE.Group`. Hence, you have to first determine the correct mesh in the group's descendants. This however depends on the asset since `OBJ` files can contain multiple mesh definitions. I've prepared a live example that demonstrates this workflow. The important code section is:

```js
var loader = new OBJLoader();
loader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/models/obj/tree.obj', function ( obj ) {

    scene.add( obj );
    mesh = obj.children[ 0 ];

} );
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bquxjf28/2/

Comment: But now only the first child will be exported, how do I add the other children of the .obj to the exported .dcr? When I add more children to 'mesh' I get "TypeError: geometry is undefined"

Comment: You have to merge all geometries before exporting via [BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/utils/BufferGeometryUtils.mergeBufferGeometries). Keep in mind that DRACO does have no understanding of meshes. You can only have one geometry per DRC file. BTW: Please accept/upvote the answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: Thanks!

I now realize that I don't understand some basic concepts of threejs yet...

If I may ask, is it even possible to export the .obj with 3 children, each with their own material, as dcr?

Comment: Unfortunately no. DRACO has no concept of materials. I suggest you use `glTF` as your primary 3D format where the usage of DRACO is clearly defined. Meaning you can use existing tools like `glTF pipeline` to DRACO compress an existing (uncompressed) glTF asset.

Comment: It's now clear, glTF is the route to follow for me, thanks again!